# Нужно вывести данные из json в php через ссылку

Tags: php, html, json

Есть ссылка на API с данными в формате `JSON` . Их значения нужно вывести в `HTML`. Я уже всё перепробовал что знал, не получается , Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.
Вот ссылка где данные хранятся.

Данные выглядят так:

```
{
    "ticker":{
        "base":"LTC",
        "target":"USD",
        "price":"46.22819121",
        "volume":"301023.36350506",
        "change":"-0.34206302"
    },
    "timestamp":1506099302,
    "success":true,
    "error":""
}
```

Я пробовал вот так:

```php
$url = file_get_content('https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/ltc-usd ');
$content = json_decode($url);
echo $content[1];
```

Ничего не выводит, мне нужно вывести `"price":"её значение";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправьте ошибку в file_get_content**s**() и добавьте в json_decode($url) второй параметр **true** -- это будет способствовать получению массива *(а не объекта)*

```
$url = file_get_contents('https://api.cryptonator.com/api/ticker/ltc-usd');
$content = json_decode($url, true);

echo $content['ticker']['price'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Непонятно откуда вы взяли `$content[1];`

Судя по вашему `json` должно быть так:

```
$content['ticker']['price'];
```

Потому что никакого массива там нет

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, чтобы `json_decode` расшифровал json в массив, вторым параметром функции, должнен идти `true`. Во-вторых, прежде чем пробовать брать какие-то данные, дампи их, вот так `print_r($data)`. И в-третьих, чтобы достать цену, вам надо обратиться после `json_decode` С вторым параметром `true`, вот таким образом `$conten[0]['ticker']['price']`.